# PHP method not returning value

Tags: php

I'm working on an app that gets data from the Runkeeper API. As with many APIs the results are broken down into pages. I'm trying to join these pages into one array that ultimately is stored as JSON on the server.

Getting and joining the results all works, but when I try to return the array (or any value) I get nothing. If I print the array I see my results. Even the echo within the conditional is working, it's just not the return.

Can someone see the error of my ways?

```
function getAllRunkeeperActivity($activities = '', $url = '/fitnessActivities'){


    if(empty($activities)){
         $activities = array(); 
    }

    $page = $this->getRunKeeperData($url);



    foreach($page->items as $item){
        $activities[] = $item;
    }

    if(isset($page->next)){

        // Getting another page
        $this->getAllRunkeeperActivity($activities, $page->next);

    } else {
        // return the result
        echo 'Return ' . count($activities) . ' items' . "\r\n"; // This happens

        // if I print_r $activities I get the expected array information

        return $activities; // this does not
    }


}
```

Comment: The `return` statement is inside your `else` clause -- is that where you're expecting the return value?

Comment: you only have one **return** in else statement ... check your code and correct it!

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: @donald123, I only want to **return** within the else. If $page->next exists if requests another page, appends that data and does itself again

Comment: @sbeliv01 yes as once $page->next doesn't exist we are on the last page so can return all data

Comment: @AbraCadaver for the purposes of trying to get it to work, it's called from another method using $steve = $this->getAllRunkeeperActivity(); print_r($steve); exit;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function returns a value if there is no $page->next value, ie. the last item.

BUT, it's returning it to the function call from the previous item, not your original one. It dies there.

In the first condition, you have to use

```
 return $this->getAllRunkeeperActivity($activities, $page->next);
```

so that the response gets passed back up the chain.